# Passing types containing SSE/AVX values

Tags: c++, visual-c++, optimization, sse, avx

Let's say I have the following

```
struct A
{
    __m256 a;
}
struct B
{
    __m256 a;
    float b;
}
```

Which of the following's generally better (if any and why) in a hard core loop?

```
void f0(A a) { ... }
void f1(A& a) { ... } //and the pointer variation
void f2(B b) { ...}
void f3(B& b) { ... } //and the pointer variation
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that it doesn't matter.

According to this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx

The calling convention states that 16-byte (and probably 32-byte) operands are always passed by reference. So even if you to pass by value, the compiler will pass it by reference underneath.

In other words, XMM and YMM registers are never passed by value in Windows. But the lower halves of XMM0-4 can still be used to pass 64-bit parameters by value.

EDIT:

In your second example with the `float` value, there is a slight difference since it will still affect whether or not `b` is passed by reference or by value.

Comment: You can pass part of a struct by val and part by ref? I thought you had to pass by ref (pointer to stack/heap) or by val (copy to stack) the entire thing?

Comment: From the performance side, the main part is whether the parameter is passed on the stack or by register. Pass-by-value parameters of 64-bits or smaller are done by register or copied to the stack. (I'm not entirely sure if this applies to structs as well since each of the members can be treated as separate parameters.) Pass by reference parameters are usually done by passing a pointer to the parameter - and this is required for all parameters larger than 64-bits.

Comment: So what I'm saying is that no matter what you do, XMM and YMM values will never be passed by register in Windows. (unless you have IPO enabled or if the function gets inlined or something)

Comment: Thanks I see. I didn't know struct members were effectively treated as separate parameters (when passing by value).